# iOS 13.1 refresh control not refreshing

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have following simple code to setup `UIRefreshControl` with `UIScrollView`

```
private func pullToRefershSetup () {
    let normalAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font:AppTheme.Fonts.font(type: .Medium, size: 14),
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:AppTheme.Colors.ColorsOfApp.colorPrimaryDark.color,

    ]

    refreshControl
        .attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refersh", attributes: normalAttributes)

    refreshControl.tintColor = AppTheme.Colors.ColorsOfApp.colorAccent.color
    self.scrollView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(callAPIToFetchData), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

This is working before iOS 13.1 even working in iOS 13 Simulator but not working in iOS13.1

Anyone has faced this issue ? Please help me

[image]

Comment: What does “not working” mean?

Comment: @matt Refresh control not firing the `valueChanged` event , usually, When you pull the tableview or scrollview it should start animating when we release.  as you can see in video gif , Refresh control not starting   animation and not firing event

Comment: Is it a table view or a scroll view? Refresh controls are not really made for use with plain scroll views. My refresh controls work just fine with my table views in iOS 13.1.

Comment: @matt this is scrollview , as from IOS 10 we have refresh control property given so it should work and working in ios12 , I can share video

Comment: Well, file a bug with Apple if you think they’ve broken existing functionality.

Comment: @matt Yes I am thinking that also, But I want to verify that from stackoverlow that I am doing anything wrong with code or not, Thank you for your help

Comment: You have not given enough code to know that. If you provide sufficient code and instructions, or a downloadable example project, I’ll be happy to look at it.

Comment: I came across this issue and noticed it works properly in an actual device but not on the simulator. Any updates @PrashantTukadiya